# How to connect textfields with database in ExtJs with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

I am new to ExtJs designer. I am developing a sample program wherein the UI contains 2 textfields - username and password, and the user is authenticated through the values in the database. I created the UI in ExtJs Designer and exported the project to RubyMine 3.1. But i am stuck up with it. Any suggestions how to connect text fields with SQL db ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you stuck up with? if you are building web application on rails for the first time, ignore extjs for sometime and work on rails first! Build some small CRUD apps and then start using extjs

Comment: I am "new" to "EXTJS", i have developed rails applications before. I want to connect extjs textfield with sqlyog (mysql) [i have exported extjs designer to rubymine 3.1 ]!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit the form to access the form values on the server side. This can be done as follows:

```
 yourform.getForm().submit(
    url: '/controller/new',
    success: function(form, action) {
        // Successfuly sent data to server...
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
       // Some error occured!
    }
 );
```

On the server side, you will have to get the parameters' values and use it with your DB.